# A name of the person’s /A name of the person

Tags: possessives

> He didn't tell me the name of the person. - correct.

Let's imagine that some person has several names. Which one would be correct?

> He didn't tell me a name of the **person**.

or

> He didn't tell me a name of the **person's**.

Answer (score 2):

Neither sentence is idiomatic. Whether you tell someone a person's full name or just part of it (*John* or *Mr Smith*) depends on the circumstances; but whatever form of address is appropriate, we wouldn't call it 'a name of theirs'.

Comment: So, "my name" is OK, but "the name of mine" is wrong?

Comment: As you probably know, _a friend of mine_ means _one of my friends_, but we would never say _a name of mine_ to mean _one of my names_.

Comment: What's the rub? Is it a grammar-related reason or something else?

Comment: Even though "He didn't tell me a name of the person." is not idiomatic, it is still technically correct?

Comment: I don't know what your language is, but in most languages people have one or more given names (first names, Christian names) and one or more names indicating what family they belong to. You don't tell people 'a name' picked at random from among these, you tell them _the_ name that's appropriate for the circumstances. A sentence can be grammatical but not mean anything.

Comment: Kate, let's switch "name" to "nickname". I am looking at the matter from the grammar angle, not from the common sense angle. Let's get out of common sense and explore pure grammar as much as it's possible.